# Missing character index of a space from jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to find the index of the first space in a string from an element's html.  In a test case where I simply set a `test` variable and check the `indexOf(' ')`, it shows up.

For example, the following results in `test` having a length of 11 characters with the first space at the 5th position, as it should.

```
var test = 'hello there';
var idxTest1 = test.indexOf(' ');
```

However, if I set my test variable to a `.text()` value from a jQuery elements `.html()`, I'm getting a `-1` for the index of the space even when `test` still appears to be equal to `'hello there'` with a length of 11 characters.

What's going on here?  http://jsfiddle.net/jhuTB/

Comment: Can you show your HTML? It should work.

Comment: @putvande see jsfiddle -- http://i.imgur.com/CVRaVgs.png

Comment: How about $(test).toString().indexOf(' ')?

Comment: odd.. `typeof test2` gives `string`. 
Trying to play with your fiddle, got same when `var test2 = document.querySelector('#test').textContent`, and the test #3 passed when `var test2 = document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML;`

Comment: I found hex value for space character is '20' for 'test' and 'A0' for 'test2'. I don't know why but it may help.

Comment: `.split(/\s/).join(' ')` will work. Issue is on encoding space character i guess  http://jsfiddle.net/jhuTB/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out, `&nbsp;` the "non breaking space" is not the typical space from the space-bar. When watching ascii characters the space from the space bar is ASCII 32 (0x20) while the nbsp is ASCII 160 (0xA0) hence the inequality.

Comment: Aha, that's it.  `var idxTest2 = test2.indexOf('\u00A0');` results in 5.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(function(){
    var test2 = $('#test').html();
    var idxTest1 = test2.indexOf('\u0026');
    console.log(idxTest1);
})
```

if using text() than try

```
$(function(){
    var test2 = $('#test').text();
    var idxTest1 = test2.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(160));
    console.log(idxTest1);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***[str.charCodeAt(index)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)*** to check the difference:

```
var test = 'hello there';
var test2 = $("<div/>").html($('#test').html()).text();
console.log(test.charCodeAt(5));  // 32
console.log(test2.charCodeAt(5)); // 160
```